# How to call a function from an other function using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I try to populate a dropdown list when the page is loaded, I want to call a void function that popualte the ddl

example for my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
FillddlList()
End Sub

Private Sub FillddlList()
ddlProducts.AddItem("car");
ddlProducts.AddItem("house");
ddlProducts.AddItem("dag");
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work... is it possible? what is the right way to do it?

Comment: neither of those procedures are Functions, and "void function" is not a VBA term.  Terminology is a good place to start.

Comment: Remove the brackets to call a procedure. Just `FillddlList` without the brackets. Only functions use brackets for parameters. Procedures don't. A `Sub` is a procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

> You can use the optional keyword CALL if you use the Call keyword to
>   call a procedure that requires arguments, argumentlist must be
>   enclosed in parentheses.

you also don't need semicolons after adding items to your combobox.

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    [Call] FillddlList
 End Sub

  Private Sub FillddlList()
    ddlProducts.AddItem ("car")
    ddlProducts.AddItem ("house")
    ddlProducts.AddItem ("dag")
  End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need `Call` at all.